# How to write sql query in laravel to fetch different exp category

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I need to fetch the data in order to do back end testing

Task - I am having Manpower table with set of columns. In the report we need to display employeese who falls under different experience category.

ex - 
0-6 months
6-12 months
12-36 months
More than 36 months...

Solution I have is get 'date of joining' and compare with the current date and caluculate months, But not getting how to group into different exp category. Please help me.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and readjust your question.

Comment: Just add a sample data and expected result to your question or replicate the data model on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com]) and add the l ink to your question.